# How to search across multiple sites using google search?

Tags: html, url, google-search

Given this URL, I can do a site search across the site specified in the query string, on Google:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=something&sitesearch=subdomain1.site-abc.com
```

This results in the following formatted string in the Google search text box:

```
something site:subdomain1.site-abc.com
```

I can also easily write a simple html form for this, like so:

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search" target="_blank">
    <input type="text"   name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="Keyword" />
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" class="button1" />
    <input type="radio"  name="sitesearch" value="subdomain1.site-abc.com" checked="checked" /> Search subdomain1.site-abc.com on Google<br />
</form>
```

Now, if I want to search across multiple sites, I can do that on Google using either of these queries in the search text box:

```
1. something site:subdomain1.site-abc.com OR subdomain2.site-abc.com
2. something site:subdomain1.site-abc.com || subdomain2.site-abc.com
3. something site:subdomain1.site-abc.com | subdomain2.site-abc.com
```

My question is, what should the query string in the URL look like, to get one of the above results in the Google search text box?

I tried these things but they do not work:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=something&sitesearch=subdomain1.site-abc.com%2B||%2Bsubdomain2.site-abc.com

https://www.google.com/search?q=something&sitesearch=subdomain1.site-abc.com%20||%20subdomain2.site-abc.com
```

First URL results in this:

```
something site:subdomain1.site-abc.com+||+subdomain2.site-abc.com
```

The second URL results in this:

```
something site:subdomain1.site-abc.com%20||%20subdomain2.site-abc.com
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the `sitesearch` URL parameter documented anywhere? Or how did you find it?

Comment: It used to be documented back in the day in google search documentation. I have this feature on one of the sites that I manage and I'm revisiting this feature after 5-6 years really. It's not surprising that the parameter is not documented any longer because google now markets this feature heavily.

Answer (score 2):

The OR is working well for me. Here an example `example site:github.com OR site:gitlab.com OR site:bitbucket.org after:2018-01-01`